# download sdk for symbian os mobile

Tags: java-me, symbian

I want to make application in symbian OS mobile which can work in all symbian os supported mobile device.
Can anyone please help me which SDK i should install and from where i get it.
And which IDE i should use.I am aware of netbeans.
IF i use netbeans or eclipse then plz show me the step to integrate that SDK with that perticular IDE.

Comment: YOu have added j2me tag ,I doubt you want to do it using java or symbian programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *Symbian Programming* then go for [*this*](http://www.symbiantutorial.org/symbian-tutorial/?1._The_Symbian_Operating_System:1.1_Installing_a_free_development_environment)
else if you mean *j2me* development then go for [*this*](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/36/J2ME_Support.html) [note: here I have recommended NB]